# Calculating Size of Encoded Byte Array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a byte array containing encoded bytes as

```
Byte* encodedBytes;
```

This contains encoded bytes. Now this array is assigned to an char pointer by typecasting.

```
 char *data = (char*)encodedBytes;
```

Now Is there any API that can give me the size of data ?
I can't use strlen() because encoded bytes may contain null character in between as well .

Comment: Basically, no, there isn't.

Comment: `encodedBytes` is not an array but (just) as pointer to a `Byte`.